# LDAP SQLite communication or link

Tags: sql, sqlite, ldap, openldap

I have openLDAP server up and running locally, I have a C API that connects to it and also queries   it, Also I have a Sqlite Database setup using ODB which is a ORM unlike hibernate in Java.
Now, I am supposed to pull data from LDAP server, and insert it into the Sqlite server.
I have tried some stuff that I found online, but nothing worked.
I am totally new to all this.
Any help will be widely appreciated

This is the code I am using to query LDAP server. I need to put the data that I get from here into a sqlite database through an object. I dont have any idea how to do that.

```
rc = ldap_search_ext_s( ld, BASEDN, SCOPE, FILTER, NULL, 0,NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &result );
if ( rc != LDAP_SUCCESS ) { 
  fprintf(stderr, "ldap_search_ext_s: %s\n", ldap_err2string(rc)); return -1;
}
for (e=ldap_first_entry(ld, result); e!=NULL; e=ldap_next_entry(ld, e)){
  if ((dn=ldap_get_dn( ld, e )) != NULL){
    printf("dn: %s\n", dn);
    ldap_memfree(dn);
  }
}
ldap_msgfree(result);
```

Comment: I tried some stuff that was related to AD while syncing this..... to be more specific, all I need is to sync LDAP and sqlite...I have no idea how to do this, please help me if you can

Comment: I need to create an object such that it pulls data from LDAP server and then pushes it into the sqlite server

Comment: Can you give us any queries you have tried?  We like to see code as it not only shows you have made an effort, but can give us an idea of what you are doing.  It may also be helpful to offer more information as to the servers (table structures, what is being moved, etc)

Comment: rc = ldap_search_ext_s( ld, BASEDN, SCOPE, FILTER, NULL, 0,NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &result );
if ( rc != LDAP_SUCCESS ) {
fprintf(stderr, "ldap_search_ext_s: %s\n", ldap_err2string(rc));
return -1;
}

for ( e = ldap_first_entry( ld, result ); e != NULL;
e = ldap_next_entry( ld, e ) ) {
if ( (dn = ldap_get_dn( ld, e )) != NULL ) {
printf( "dn: %s\n", dn );
ldap_memfree( dn );
}
}

ldap_msgfree( result );

Comment: This is the code I am using to query LDAP server. I need to put the data that I get from here into a sqlite database through an object. I dont have any idea how to do that.